# Emulator not starting up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, qemu

Latest download of everything running on Vista.
I had everything working, emulation working, etc., but at some point it stopped and I had not messed with the SDK or anything, still slogging thru the tutorials...

Now when I Run | Run the emulator does not start up on the screen. I think it happened sometime after I tried Run | Debug to see what that would do (which was nothing) but that doesn't seem like it should cause this problem.

The console shows was showing a launching of a new emulator, and the emulator responding with the GNU message and that's the last output. Now after a restart, the console is showing nothing, just "Aptana JavaScript Scripting Console Started". The Task Manager does not show the emulator in the Process list.

I tried running emulator-x86 -avd my_avd and I get:
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator-x86 -avd my_avd
qemu: linux kernel too old to load a ram disk C:\Android\android-sdk/platforms\a
ndroid-7\images/kernel-qemu, C:\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-7\images\
/ramdisk.img, qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=gold
fish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1

Is the installation corrupted somehow?

BTW, I installed the whole SDK and NDK, but I'm reusing Eclipse from when I was doing some webOS development on the Palm Pre.

Comment: Looks like the emulator-x86 is for x86 code. I tried running the -arm and it starts up, and after a few complaints from Eclipse, I can actually run HelloWorld on it. However, if I kill the emulator, Eclipse won't start it up. Apparently the emulator start-up in Eclipse is broken. I'd rather not reinstall everything because it might break again.

Comment: One trick I saw was to go to Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Android -> Devices but that is blank for me. But if I manually start the emulator, the emulator-5554 appears in the Devices list. I do get some "Can't bind to local 8601 for debugger" errors though. And after the manully-started emulator is up, I get a whole list of items under Devices, and the com.android.inputmethod.pinyin 8601/8700 has an error icon, the rest are OK.

Comment: And I do have a device in the Window|Android SDK and AVD Manager window with a green checkmark. But Eclipse seems to not be able to start it.

Comment: I got no answer, so I uninstalled Eclipse and downloaded and reinstalled. I suspect something might have been corrupted because I had used it to debug webOS. It does seem to be working better now, so that appears to be the solution. Don't forget to NOT install the SDK under c:\program files because that space screws up the emulator startup script.